# Limit length of longtext field in SELECT results

Tags: mysql, sql, substring, longtext

I'm executing a SELECT query on a table in MySQL using the command-line interface (not a GUI client):

> SELECT * FROM blog_entry;

One of blog_entry's fields is of type 'longtext' and is such a long piece of text that when the result is displayed in my terminal the display of rows takes more than one line. This causes an ugly mess of a display, where columns aren't easily visible. What technique can I use in my SELECT query that would limit the number of characters displayed for each field so that the printed row results don't overflow to new lines?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use MySQL's `SUBSTRING` function, as described in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring). Like:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(`text`, 1, 100) FROM blog_entry;
```

To select first 100 chars.

Comment: I found that the single inverted commas around 'text' was not required if 'text' is a field name

Answer (score 33):

You can use the **[`LEFT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_left)** function to get only the first characters:

```
SELECT LEFT(LongField, 20) AS LongField_First20chars
FROM ...
```

Comment: You don't really need the `as LongField_First20chars` unless you want to make it easier to use from a program.

Comment: @poolie of course you don't. But it's good practice to have an alias in the returned columns.

Comment: Quote the AS clause for pretty column names: "LongField (short view)".

Answer (score 15):

The best way to clean up the readability of the results from a query in your terminal window is to use the mysql pager, not modifying your query as that can be too cumbersome.

1. Set the pager:

   `mysql> pager less -S`
2. Do your query:

   `mysql> SELECT * FROM ...`

This will put your results in a more readable format. You can use your arrow keys to page up and down and left and right to see the full table. Just press `Q` to get out of pager mode for that query, and then just run

```
mysql> pager more
```

to return to the normal output river if you want.

Comment: Seems like `-S` would chop the whole line, not each column.

Comment: Rick, it does seem to chop (needed) columns in an intelilgent manner (IDK how)

Answer (score 5):

```
Select Cast(theLongTextField As VarChar(100)) From blogEntry
```